# Tools for understanding big projects for android and ios

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, xcode

I need some tools to explore an old project (iOS and Android) that is in a legacy state. I want to see what happens when I push a button so I can better understand what is going on before jumping in and modifying.

For example:
On login the controller gets the data master (singleton) and asks it to check the credentials and responds back (with and event or trough a delegate), if everything is ok it asks the application (appdelegate or Application) to flush all the controllers in the stack and start fresh with a new controller that is the main screen.

Are there any tools that can help me do that. Putting log on all the function is not an option since the log is already overloaded.

The projects are big so going manual on it will take a long time, I need something to help me optimise the analysis process.

Thank you for your time,
Bogdan

Comment: Just do it the old-fashioned way by importing the project into an IDE and activate the Debug mode. I'm not aware of any tool that does what you want

Comment: I am still researching some ways, I am trying to do this whit android profiling tools and objective c method swizzling. The debug log tools do not offer easy ways to do this, you have to use the log command, and the project is bloated with logs.